# How to deal with this integral equation?

Tags: integration

While reading a paper I saw the following integral equation.

$$\frac{1}{g} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\prod_{\sigma}\frac{\mathrm{d}p_{\sigma}}{2\pi}) \frac{\delta(\Sigma_{\sigma}  p_{\sigma})}{(\prod_{\sigma} (1+\frac{2 \mathrm{sin}(p_{\sigma}/2)}{m}) -1)} \, ,\, \mathrm{with}\, \sigma = {1,2,3,4} $$

But there was no solution given for it. To learn more about this integral equation, I would like to solve it. Sadly I don't even know how to begin/deal with this equation or more precisely with the integral itself. Hopefully someone can give me a hint or two.

Comment: Does the equation somehow tie in with physics? If not you might want to reconsider and post this to the Mathematics stack exchange. Sorry I can't help you, but you might want to check out Paul Nahin's new book "Inside Interesting Integrals". He has lots of good tips, tricks for solving definite integrals. Good luck!

Comment: The paper is about non-relativistic fermions (in two dimensional euclidean space-time) and with this integral one should be able to determine the coupling g. Thanks for the book recommendation - I will check it out!

Comment: Maybe you could add a definition for each symbol. This can help others to find a solution to your problem. For example, what is delta in your case?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper?

Comment: `But there was no solution given for it.` The equal sign suggests that the solution is $\frac1g$, no? Why was it not solved in the paper? Does it even make sense to solve it?

Comment: it was mentioned that one could use this integral equation to calculate the coupling g. but the coupling was not used furthermore, so they simply did not calculate it. I figured out how to do the $\sigma = 0$ case. the $\sigma = 0, 1$ case is a bit harder but I am makeing some progress. 
Sad to see it downvoted by someone, it is a legitimate question...

Comment: You could try to write the delta function as a Fourier integral and interchanging the order of integration. Then you have unrestricted integrals over the momenta and you compute the Fourier integral after the integrations over the momenta.